# How to verify contents of files has been changed from previous version

Tags: java, c++, filesystems

I have to write an application which will run as a service and notify other application whenever contents of files are changed. File size can be small or huge so it will not be appropriate to copy files to backup location on each run of application and compare current file contents with the backup created by previous run.

Can anyone suggest me some method by which I can verify that contents of file has changed from previous run of application without taking backup of files.

Thanks

Comment: Store a hash of the file and compare the hashes.

Comment: Normally such backup services check file modification timestamps.

Comment: compare the checksum between the files

Comment: Depends on the size of the file, and the effort you're willing to go through ... if hashing the file is too expensive because of the size of the file, how about just looking at the file size and timestamp?

Comment: what do you mean by hashing the file. I am certainly checking file size but it can still give some wrong result like if somebody simply add blank space then that would trigger wrong alarm.

Comment: @user3494614 If someone entered a blank space then the file is in fact different.

Comment: @user3494614 You come up with a [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) for the file and then you store it.  When you run again you compute the checksum against the current file and compare it to the stored one.  If they are different then the file has changed.

Comment: "File size can be small or huge..." Realistically, that pretty much means you can't do checksums or hashes.  How could you possibly keep up with changing files if you have to track a few tens of thousands of files adding up to hundreds of GB if not a few TB?  You have to rely solely on modification timestamp - there's no point in computing a checksum to find out if a file changed - that means if it does change, it will have to be read *twice* - once to get the checksum, and once more to process the changes. Doing things based on discovering changes to "huge" files is not a good idea.